# What is different between Pick<T, "properties"> and T["properties"] in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm typescript beginner.

What is difference between `Pick` and T["properties"] index reference?

For example:

```
interface Generic {
   red: number
   apple: string;
   
}

type RedType = Pick<Generic, "red">
type RedType2 = Generic["red"]
```

Comment: The difference: the first does not work, the second does. After you fix it to `Pick<>` - their types are different: check at https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first example picks only certain properties of an object and returns an object type

```
type RedType = Pick<Generic, 'red'>; // { red: number }
```

The second example gives you the type of the referenced property on an object

```
type RedType2 = Generic["red"]; // number
```